# ClientScript doesn't work in codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I created the script to call the javascript in code behind. However it has an error. I didn't figure out what is wrong. Would someone point it out to me. Thanks.

There is my code:

```
Dim strScript As String = "<script language=javascript>alert('test/page1.aspx?loctionFolder=
                      Server.HtmlEncode(hdFolderLocation.Value) & "');return false; </script>"

            If Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "download") Then
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "download", strScript, True)
            End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RegisterStartupScript Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx)'s last parameter is ***addScriptTags***.

In your case, you set it as `strScript, True)`, so you ***do not need script tag***.

```
Dim strScript As String = "alert('test/page1.aspx?loctionFolder=" & 
   Server.HtmlEncode(hdFolderLocation.Value) & "');return false;";
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed double quote and concatenation before `Server.HtmlEncode(hdFolderLocation.Value)`

```
Dim strScript As String = "<script language=javascript>alert('test/page1.aspx?loctionFolder=" & 
                      Server.HtmlEncode(hdFolderLocation.Value) & "');return false; </script>"

        If Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "download") Then
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "download", strScript, True)
        End If
```